# how to match '/' but NOT '/*' NOR '*/' in postgreSQL?

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

### **1/ The context:**

I am about to end the migration of a mySQL database to a new postgreSQL one. In this context, I had to "translate" my routines from mySQL to postgreSQL.

I noticed that the behaviour of the two languages is different in case of a division by zero. If you execute the following query:

```
SELECT a/b as result FROM t ;
```

in mySQL, the lines for which the column `b` equals 0 will simply return NULLs. On the contrary, in postgreSQL, you will get the following error:

```
ERROR: division by zero
SQL state: 22012
```

To prevent this, you can obviously do the following:

```
SELECT 
a / NULLIF(b,0)
as result
FROM t;
```

and you will get the same behaviour than in mySQL (I prefer this behaviour because I find it more robust).

---

### **2/ The issue:**

The thing is, I noticed this phenomenon only after "translating" almost all of my routines from one language to the other. It means that I have not implemented this "anti-division by zero" solution in the first routines I translated. Therefore, I want to find all the routines that include divisions in the calculations, in order to correct them, so I can avoid multiple "division by zero" errors during the execution.

I naively tried to execute the following query to get the names of all the routines that I have to edit:

```
SELECT routine_name FROM information_schema.routines 
WHERE routine_definition LIKE '%/%' 
AND routine_schema = 'myschema' ;
```

The problem is that this query will also return the names of all the routines that include at least one comment delimited by the characters `/* */`. And I don't want to get these (because that's almost all of my routines).

---

### **3/ The question:**

Therefore, I want to get the routines where `routine_definition` matches `/` but **not** `*/` **nor** `/*`. I have the feeling that [regular expression matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-matching.html) could help me in doing that, but I have almost never used these and I feel a little bit lost even after reading the documentation I just linked.

Comment: Unrelated, but: you can simplify your expression to `a / nullif(b,0)`

Comment: Well, I didn't know about NULLIF so thank you, it is indeed simpler!

Comment: I will edit my question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure if that covers all cases, but as a first shot: `where  routine_definition ~ '[^*]/[^*]'`

Comment: I've got false positives using your suggestion, i.e. the query returned the name of a routine that has a /* */ comment in its definition, but that doesn't use the / character anywhere else.

Comment: The standard approach in regex implementations with negative lookahead/behind is '(?<!\*)/(?!\*)' but it seems that lookbehind is only available since 9.6, and since '/' at the beginning/end of the `routine_definition` is, I guess, not interesting either the suggestion by @a_horse_with_no_name should IMHO cover all cases.

Comment: The false positive looks unexpected. Can you produce a simplified example using eg. `where 'some string with /* */' ~ '[^*]/[^*]'`

Comment: It looks that this behaviour is caused by the linebreaks in the routine definition. Indeed, if you have a `/* comment */` then a linebreak and then some query, for instance `'SELECT ...'`, the `routine_definition` will be: `/* comment */SELECT ...`, and I think that the lack of space between the `*/` and the next line of the query are the reason for these false positives.

Comment: But I think I will find my way out by using `replace` to replace the `/*` and the `*/` with empty strings. It is not very clean, but this should do.

Comment: The answer from @jmriego below seems to explain why @a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion didn't work. The `*` character needs to be escaped so it should be `[^\*]` intead of `[^*]`.

Comment: @R.Bourgeon: I don't think the `*` needs to be escaped inside `[  ]`

Comment: @R.Bourgeon it does not need to be escaped. `SELECT 's' ~ '[*]'` = false.

Comment: indeed my latest statement was false and I apologize about that (I made this statement before testing it, and this was not a very scientific way of doing things).
 @MichałPolitowski when I use a minimal statement, such as `SELECT ('/* comment */SELECT'  ~ '[^*]/[^*]')` it indeed returns `false`, but with one of my own routines that begins the same way and that does NOT have any `/` in the rest of the `routine_definition`, the result was `true`. This is very strange.

Comment: OK I was wrong all the time, there was a `/` inside the text of the comment itself. Therefore @a_horse_with_no_name's comment is a correct solution. Can you please post it as a proper answer?